# Javascript from cytoscape is not a function

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

My javascript component is not rendering and I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: $(...).cytoscape is not a function
```

Here is the code that throws the error.

Essentially I'm trying to isolate what javascript renders to the contents of the row. When I run this without nesting it in a container then It work fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title>Main Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/graph4.css">


    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


  </head>
  <body>
    
    
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="background-color:lavender;">
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/api/cytoscape.js-latest/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
          <script>
  $(function(){ // on dom ready
  
  $('#cy').cytoscape({
      layout: {
          name: 'cose',
      padding: 10,
      randomize: true
    },
    
    style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
      .selector('node')
        .css({
          'shape': 'data(faveShape)',
          'width': 'mapData(weight, 40, 80, 20, 60)',
          'content': 'data(name)',
          'text-valign': 'center',
          'text-outline-width': 2,
          'text-outline-color': 'data(faveColor)',
          'background-color': 'data(faveColor)',
          'color': '#fff'
        })
      .selector(':selected')
        .css({
          'border-width': 3,
          'border-color': '#333'
        })
      .selector('edge')
        .css({
          'curve-style': 'bezier',
          'opacity': 0.666,
          'width': 'mapData(strength, 70, 100, 2, 6)',
          'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
          'source-arrow-shape': 'circle',
          'line-color': 'data(faveColor)',
          'source-arrow-color': 'data(faveColor)',
          'target-arrow-color': 'data(faveColor)'
        })
      .selector('edge.questionable')
        .css({
          'line-style': 'dotted',
          'target-arrow-shape': 'diamond'
        })
      .selector('.faded')
        .css({
          'opacity': 0.25,
          'text-opacity': 0
        }),
  
    elements: {
      nodes: [
        { data: { id: 'j', name: 'Jerry', weight: 65, faveColor: '#6FB1FC', faveShape: 'triangle' } },
        { data: { id: 'e', name: 'Elaine', weight: 45, faveColor: '#EDA1ED', faveShape: 'ellipse' } },
        { data: { id: 'k', name: 'Kramer', weight: 75, faveColor: '#86B342', faveShape: 'octagon' } },
        { data: { id: 'g', name: 'George', weight: 70, faveColor: '#F5A45D', faveShape: 'rectangle' } }
      ],
      edges: [
        { data: { source: 'j', target: 'e', faveColor: '#6FB1FC', strength: 90 } },
        { data: { source: 'j', target: 'k', faveColor: '#6FB1FC', strength: 70 } },
        { data: { source: 'j', target: 'g', faveColor: '#6FB1FC', strength: 80 } },
       
        { data: { source: 'e', target: 'j', faveColor: '#EDA1ED', strength: 95 } },
        { data: { source: 'e', target: 'k', faveColor: '#EDA1ED', strength: 60 }, classes: 'questionable' },
        
        { data: { source: 'k', target: 'j', faveColor: '#86B342', strength: 100 } },
        { data: { source: 'k', target: 'e', faveColor: '#86B342', strength: 100 } },
        { data: { source: 'k', target: 'g', faveColor: '#86B342', strength: 100 } },
        
        { data: { source: 'g', target: 'j', faveColor: '#F5A45D', strength: 90 } }
      ]
    },
    
    ready: function(){
      window.cy = this;
      
      // giddy up
    }
  });
  
  }); // on dom ready
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  </script>
          <div id="cy"></div>
   <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="background-color:lavenderblush";>
        Timeline
    </div>
  </div>







   





</div>

<footer class="footer">
<p>
<center>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark" aria-hidden="true"></span>
Test
</center>
</p>
</footer>

    
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have an anonymous closure function that you deem `when dom is ready` why not explicity make a `$(document).ready...` and see if it works then?

Comment: What does that mean anyway. Dom Ready. Only when the page has completely loaded up will the script run.

Comment: The issue may have to do with when I initialize the graph. According to other SO post. The graph has to be initialized after the bootstrap.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#cy').cytoscape({
  layout: {
    name: 'cose',
    padding: 10,
    randomize: true
  },
  ...
};
```

needs to be changed to

```
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: $('#cy'),
  layout: {
      name: 'cose',
    padding: 10,
    randomize: true
  },
  ...
};
```

as per the directions at http://js.cytoscape.org/#getting-started/initialisation

This will resolve your error, but I'm not sure if it's rendering what you were hoping it would render. I hope this at least gets you one step closer to your desired behavior!

Comment: That helped resolve the error but now I get an error about mutations. From what I have read on other post it bootstrap and cytoscape need to rendered in a specific order due to how cytoscape works with dimensions.

Comment: @ForgottenKahz Can you update your question (or ask a new question) with what you're now trying to do? Please be sure to write about what you've tried! It's always helpful when you can provide this information, as it both forces you to think about critically analyzing "what's broken," and also provides everybody more information to help you with (other than "it doesn't work"). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the jQuery object thusly :

```
(function($) {
     //dom and jquery is ready
 })(jQuery);
```

try it :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title>Main Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


  </head>
  <body>
    
    
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="background-color:lavender;">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/2.7.13/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
          <script>
  (function($) { // on dom ready
  
  $('#cy').cytoscape({
      layout: {
          name: 'cose',
      padding: 10,
      randomize: true
    },
    
    style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
      .selector('node')
        .css({
          'shape': 'data(faveShape)',
          'width': 'mapData(weight, 40, 80, 20, 60)',
          'content': 'data(name)',
          'text-valign': 'center',
          'text-outline-width': 2,
          'text-outline-color': 'data(faveColor)',
          'background-color': 'data(faveColor)',
          'color': '#fff'
        })
      .selector(':selected')
        .css({
          'border-width': 3,
          'border-color': '#333'
        })
      .selector('edge')
        .css({
          'curve-style': 'bezier',
          'opacity': 0.666,
          'width': 'mapData(strength, 70, 100, 2, 6)',
          'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
          'source-arrow-shape': 'circle',
          'line-color': 'data(faveColor)',
          'source-arrow-color': 'data(faveColor)',
          'target-arrow-color': 'data(faveColor)'
        })
      .selector('edge.questionable')
        .css({
          'line-style': 'dotted',
          'target-arrow-shape': 'diamond'
        })
      .selector('.faded')
        .css({
          'opacity': 0.25,
          'text-opacity': 0
        }),
  
    elements: {
      nodes: [
        { data: { id: 'j', name: 'Jerry', weight: 65, faveColor: '#6FB1FC', faveShape: 'triangle' } },
        { data: { id: 'e', name: 'Elaine', weight: 45, faveColor: '#EDA1ED', faveShape: 'ellipse' } },
        { data: { id: 'k', name: 'Kramer', weight: 75, faveColor: '#86B342', faveShape: 'octagon' } },
        { data: { id: 'g', name: 'George', weight: 70, faveColor: '#F5A45D', faveShape: 'rectangle' } }
      ],
      edges: [
        { data: { source: 'j', target: 'e', faveColor: '#6FB1FC', strength: 90 } },
        { data: { source: 'j', target: 'k', faveColor: '#6FB1FC', strength: 70 } },
        { data: { source: 'j', target: 'g', faveColor: '#6FB1FC', strength: 80 } },
       
        { data: { source: 'e', target: 'j', faveColor: '#EDA1ED', strength: 95 } },
        { data: { source: 'e', target: 'k', faveColor: '#EDA1ED', strength: 60 }, classes: 'questionable' },
        
        { data: { source: 'k', target: 'j', faveColor: '#86B342', strength: 100 } },
        { data: { source: 'k', target: 'e', faveColor: '#86B342', strength: 100 } },
        { data: { source: 'k', target: 'g', faveColor: '#86B342', strength: 100 } },
        
        { data: { source: 'g', target: 'j', faveColor: '#F5A45D', strength: 90 } }
      ]
    },
    
    ready: function(){
      window.cy = this;
      
      // giddy up
    }
  });
  
  }); // on dom ready
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  </script>
          <div id="cy"></div>
   <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="background-color:lavenderblush";>
        Timeline
    </div>
  </div>







   





</div>

<footer class="footer">
<p>
<center>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark" aria-hidden="true"></span>
Test
</center>
</p>
</footer>

    
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sound like is might have have worked but the run code snippet ended up with the same result. The graph that the javascript was supposed to render is missing!